# How can I get a cursor from a Content Provider using a database that was created in memory

Tags: android-contentprovider

**I create a database in memory as follows:**

```
public class DbIoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DbIo.db";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = ":memory:";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
       public DbIoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
//        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        super(context, null, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
 .........
 }
```

**In my content provider the query is as follows:**

```
 @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor retCursor;
        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case LABEL:
                retCursor = db.query(
                        IOContract.IoEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder
                );
                break;

            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
```

**In my activity the cursor is:**

```
    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(cpUri, null, selection, argms, null);
```

**When I create the database using DATABASE_NAME, the database is created on disk and I get the cursor back.**

```
     public DbIoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        super(context, null, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

**When I create it in memory using null, I get no element in the cursor - though the cursor returned is not  null .**

```
  public DbIoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
//        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        super(context, null, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

**Is there a way that i can get a valid cursor when the database is created in memory and how can I do it?
     Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: Did you add data to your database ? When your database is just in-memory, it won't save data between runs of your application, meaning that any query before adding data is going to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you XGouchet for your answer.  I resolved my issue in the following way: I had read that a database created in memory is visible only to the activity that created it. Therefore, I created the database in the Content Provider in the OnCreate() method.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
         myDbData = new DatabaseData();
         myDb = new IODatabaseHelper(getContext());
         initializeDb();  // method that populates the database
         if (myDb == null) {
             ret = false;
         }
         return true;
    }
```